# give ads_id to table images for every images uploaded in PHP

Tags: php

I have some simple form for user to upload ads , it look like this :
[image]

As you can see there is a Picture form so that user can put multiple picture in their ads.

I have a table for **images** which look like this :
[image]

As you can see the **ads_id** column is always 0 , i have not found a way to put **ads_id** for every images uploaded .

The **ads** table look like this :
[image]

And here is my uploader.php file which i use to perform the action :

```
<?php
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$title = $status = $category = $location = $description = $mark = $notes = $user_id =  "";
$statusMsg = $errorMsg = $insertValuesSQL = $errorUpload = $errorUploadType = '';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

// Include the database configuration file
include 'session.php';

// File upload configuration
$targetDir = "upload/";
$allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif');

//giving a value
$title = $_POST["title"];
$status = $_POST["status"];
$category = $_POST["category"];
$location = $_POST["location"];
$description = $_POST["description"];
$mark = $_POST["mark"];
$notes = $_POST["notes"];
$user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];

mysqli_query($koneksi, "INSERT INTO ads(user_id,category_id,status,title,location,mark,description,notes,date_posted) VALUES ('$user_id', '$category','$status', '$title','$location', '$mark','$description', '$notes',NOW())");
//images uploader
if(!empty(array_filter($_FILES['images']['name']))){
    foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key=>$val){
        // File upload path
        $fileName = basename($_FILES['images']['name'][$key]);
        $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;

        // Check whether file type is valid
        $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
            // Upload file to server
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key], $targetFilePath)){
                // Image db insert sql
                $insertValuesSQL .= "('".$fileName."', NOW()),";
            }else{
                $errorUpload .= $_FILES['images']['name'][$key].', ';
            }
        }else{
            $errorUploadType .= $_FILES['images']['name'][$key].', ';
        }
    }

    if(!empty($insertValuesSQL)){
        $insertValuesSQL = trim($insertValuesSQL,',');
        // Insert image file name into database
        $insert = $koneksi->query("INSERT INTO images (file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES $insertValuesSQL");
        if($insert){
            $errorUpload = !empty($errorUpload)?'Upload Error: '.$errorUpload:'';
            $errorUploadType = !empty($errorUploadType)?'File Type Error: '.$errorUploadType:'';
            $errorMsg = !empty($errorUpload)?'<br/>'.$errorUpload.'<br/>'.$errorUploadType:'<br/>'.$errorUploadType;
            $statusMsg = "Files are uploaded successfully.".$errorMsg;
        }else{
            $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
}else{
    $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
}

// Display status message
echo $statusMsg;
header('refresh:1; url=index.php');
}
?>
```

**How do i assign the ads_id to every image selected from user when they post a new ads ?**

Comment: You need to get the id of the last inserted query, like using [`mysqli_insert_id()`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_insert_id.asp)

Comment: i just doing some research about mysqli_insert_id() and that is exactly what i needed. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should add UPDATE query to your script, the best place for this is after `if($insert){` To get last insert ID you can use [mysqli_insert_id()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_insert_id.asp) like Carl mention, here is example:

```
if($insert){
    $last_inserted_id = $insert->insert_id;
    $update_ads_id = $koneksi->query("UPDATE images SET ads_id = 2"); // or what id you want.
```

Notice: You should learn how to implement more security scripts, using [prepared statements](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the last inserted record's id and then use it. You can do something like this:

```
if (mysqli_query($koneksi, "INSERT INTO ads(user_id,category_id,status,title,location,mark,description,notes,date_posted) VALUES ('$user_id', '$category','$status', '$title','$location', '$mark','$description', '$notes',NOW())")) {
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($koneksi); // now you can insert this with rest of your data to your images table...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the **mysqli_insert_id()** is the answer , thanks to Morgan,Saud and Carl

i ended up with placing **last_inserted_id** after my first query so that it get the lastest **ads_id**

```
mysqli_query($koneksi, "INSERT INTO ads(user_id,category_id,status,title,location,mark,description,notes,date_posted) VALUES ('$user_id', '$category','$status', '$title','$location', '$mark','$description', '$notes',NOW())");
$last_inserted_id = $insert->insert_id;
```

after that i inserted it on my image query

```
$insertValuesSQL .= "('$last_inserted_id','".$fileName."', NOW()),";
$insert = $koneksi->query("INSERT INTO images (ads_id,file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES $insertValuesSQL");
```